# Working Directory : null environment when running Process.Builder on android

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, su, android-4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-5

I am using two phones, Galaxy Nexus(JellyBean) and Nexus 5(KitKat). I am trying to execute a script which exists in

> /data/folder/scripts/run.sh

I use Process.Builder to build the command. This command is built by getting

> Environment.getDataDirectory().toString() + "/folder/scripts/run.sh"

There are no issues running this on the Galaxy Nexus but when I run it on the Nexus 5, I catch an exception when I run the process.start(). The output which I get contains:

> Error running exec(). Command: [/data/folder/scripts/run.sh, "param"]. Working directory: null Environment: [ADNROID_ROOT=/system ... ]

The directory structure of my scripts is the same on both files.

EDIT:

So I was looking at the logcat as soon as I load the application and I think I've pinpointed the issue.

There's an ERROR saying Manifest file not found.
WARNING: java.io.FileNotFoundException /data/folder/Manifest: open failed EACCESS (Permission Denied).

This doesn't come up for the Galaxy Nexus which is running JellyBean. Is it some security issue with KitKat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to not having root access. Fixed when SuperSu granted permission to the application.